# Which is the best way to organize ViewModel in WP7 app?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone

I need to show data reading from local XML for a books app. I have to show data in different ways, eg. list of authors, list of editors, list of genres, etc then showing the book details.

Which is the best way to organize ViewModels? Can I have a single BooksViewModel class with the various GetAuthors, GetEditors, etc or should I have AuthorsViewModel, EditorsViewModel, etc?

Data is present in local XML and cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewModel follows the view. So if you're having a separate view (page) for each type you wish to display the information for, then yes, several viewmodels makes sense.

But if your for instance, have a single view for all the data, for example a pivot, and then having a individual pivotitem for each data type, then you would use a single viewmodel, with several observable properties.